# How do I keep asking the user a question over and over again until they enter the correct field of value?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am a rookie coder here and I can't seem to figure out what to add to my code here to get it right. It is supposed to ask the user again if they do not answer the question "Do you want to make another calculation Y or N?" correctly. I want it to repetitively ask the user to enter y or n if they enter something else. I feel like it is obvious I am just missing it. This is for school, to be clear.

I've tried nesting a do while loop and an if statement but only to get run time errors

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int base, exponent;
    long int result = 1;
    char choice;
    int i;

    do
    {
        cout << "This program raises a number to a specific power." << endl;

        cout << "\nEnter a base integer greater than 1: ";
        cin >> base;

        cout << "\nEnter  an exponent integer to raise that number to: ";
        cin >> exponent;

        for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
        {
            result = result * base;
        }

        cout << "\n" << base << " to the power of " << exponent << " = " << result << endl;

        result = 1; 

        // ***** HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP, WHAT TO 
        //       DO IF THEY DONT ENTER Y OR N.....

        cout << "\nWould you like to make another calculation? Y or N: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

    }
    while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

    cout << "Good bye, then. Have a good day.\n" << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

When I tried adding a nested do while loop, and entered a character answer other than y or n, it would go to a part of the program it should not have.

*this is my first question so I hope I've done this correctly

Comment: Wrap the prompt in another `do while`

Comment: Instead of stuffing everything in `main`, create a function that prompts the user and returns the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `do-while` loop to wrap the input section.

```cpp
do
{
    cout << "This program raises a number to a specific power." << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter a base integer greater than 1: ";
    cin >> base;

    cout << "\nEnter  an exponent integer to raise that number to: ";
    cin >> exponent;

    for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }

    cout << "\n" << base << " to the power of " << exponent << " = " << result << endl;

    result = 1; 

    do
    {
        cout << "\nWould you like to make another calculation? Y or N: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
     } while (choice != 'y' && choice != 'Y' && choice != 'n' && choice != 'N');

}
while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
```

Comment: Right on, this was exactly what I needed my man. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to think organically here. Let me do a procedural approach.

We begin by bringing your formulations into a more technical form, until it is syntactically and semantically working. Let's start by transforming it into this:

```
void process_things()
{
    ...
    while(still_require_answer)
    {
        ask_for_answer();
    }
    ...
}
```

This is very close to how you formulate it verbally, yes? Now, let's flesh it out.

```
string ask_for_answer(bool& still_require_answer);

void process_things()
{
    ...

    string answer = "";
    bool still_require_answer = true;

    while(still_require_answer)
    {
        answer = ask_for_answer(still_require_answer);
    }

    ...
}

// hope you understand the concept of a reference here,
// that is what the ampersand (&) does, if not, ask
string ask_for_answer(bool& still_require_answer)
{
    string answer = ""; // always initialize
    cout << "State answer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;

    if(answer == "Y" or ...)
    {
        still_require_answer = false;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Hope this helps you. In the long run, you might want to go OOP and use classes here. The code here is a little bit verbose, but orderly.

Note that I have put the routine in a new function `process_things`. Anything that is more than a few lines which you can name you should think about making a function (or a class method). Your `main` should be quite small. Cutting things down into smaller units helps you keeping thisng orderly and makes the design of each single unit easy (*divide-and-conquer*) and allows you to quicker locate problems as you can test every function separately (later, this leads to automated *unit tests*).

One could also take the while and put it into it's own function `string ask_until_valid_answer();`, and if we do that, dissolve `ask_for_answer` and put it's content there. What I want to focus on is to have it organically, that is use self-descriptive names which explain the program while reading it, and to cut the program into understandable units. Here would be this other layout:

```
string ask_until_valid_answer();

void process_things()
{
    ...

    string answer = ask_until_valid_answer();

    ...
}


string ask_until_valid_answer()
{
    string answer = "";
    bool still_require_answer = true;

    while(still_require_answer)
    {
        cout << "State answer: ";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;

        if(answer == "Y" or ...)
        {
            still_require_answer = false;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate the information here. I'm just now getting to functions so I will have a great reference here. Many thanks to you for helping a struggling student.